# click listener on table td while using for loop to assign data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a table for a part of my assignment and I am having a hard time implementing event listener the right way. It seems like the data that I am trying to display `<td>here</td>`is fixed and I don't know how to fix this issue.

There's some great help on event listeners on table rows however I couldn't find an example that uses loops to assign the data.

Here is my code:

```
var functionCreate = function(intWidth, intHeight) {
    var myRow;
    var intCell;

    $('#output').append('<table border = \"1\">');

    for(var i = 0; i< intHeight;i++){

        $('#output').find('table').append('<tr>');
        for(var j = 0; j < intWidth; j ++){
            intCell = 'click me';

            $('#output').find('tr:last').append('<td>'+intCell)

            $('#output').on('click',"td", function(){

                $(this).text((i+1).toString()+'.'+(j+1).toString());//(row.col)
            })
        }
    }

        return jQuery('output');
};
```

what happens is that the final row.col value is assigned to all `<td></td>` here. I don't know how to give each one a different value.

so if I pass `functionCreate(3,5)`. All data in rows (after click) become `5.3`.

I guess my question is how do I assign the click behavior to the relevant `<td></td>` only? Or is there any other way to pass the data?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Glossary/Hoisting):

### Minimal reproduction of your error

```js
// Demonstration of how easy it is for this to mess up your loops.
    
    var txt = ["a","b","c"];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) { 
       var msg = txt[i];
        setTimeout(function() { alert(msg); }, i*1000);        
    }
    
    // Alerts 'c', 'c', 'c'
```

### Solution

```js
// Pattern to avoid that by binding to variable in another function.

var txt = ["a","b","c"];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {    
    setTimeout((function(msg) { 
      return function() { alert(msg); } 
    })(txt[i]), i*1000);        
}

// Alerts 'a','b','c'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use data attribute to avoid hoisting issue.

```
var functionCreate = function(intWidth, intHeight) {
    var myRow;
    var intCell;

    $('#output').append('<table border = \"1\">');

    for(var i = 0; i< intHeight;i++){

        $('#output').find('table').append('<tr>');
        for(var j = 0; j < intWidth; j ++){
            intCell = 'click me';

            var cell = $('<td>'+intCell).data('row', i+1).data('col', j+1);
            $('#output').find('tr:last').append(cell);
        }
    }

        return jQuery('output');
};



$('#output').on('click',"td", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var row = $this.data('row');
    var col = $this.data('col');

    $this.text(row+'.'+col);//(row.col)
})
```

and, event registration can be moved to outside from loop.